# Entity Framework left Join two databases

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am in need of joining a list to a database query using entity framework.
Basically, I have two databases where I need to outer join a table from one database to a table in another database.
In order to do this, I thought of getting a list from database one and then left join it to the query of the second query.
The problem is, I have to return the result as an IQueryable, so the consumer of the method can do additional filtering on the query before it being executed.

I have tried two different methods:

Option 1:

```
 Public Shared Function List() As IQueryable(Of ContractEquipment)
' Get Subcontractors from Database 1
Dim subcontractors As List(Of SubContractor) = GetSubContractorList().ToList()
' Query Database 2
Return (From c In DB.ContractEquipments
        Select New With {
            .ContractID = c.ContractID,
            .EquipmentID = c.EquipmentID,
            .Inactive = c.Inactive,
            .SubContractorName = (From x In subcontractors Where c.SubContractorID = x.SubContractorID Select x.Name).FirstOrDefault()
        })
```

End Function

Option 2:

```
Public Shared Function List() As IQueryable(Of ContractEquipment)
' Get Subcontractors from Database 1
Dim subcontractors As List(Of SubContractor) = GetSubContractorList().ToList()
' Query Database 2
Return (From c In DB.ContractEquipments
        Group Join s in subcontractors on c.SubContractorID equals s.SubContractorID into tblSubContractors = Group
        Select New With {
            .ContractID = c.ContractID,
            .EquipmentID = c.EquipmentID,
            .Inactive = c.Inactive,
            .SubContractorName = tblSubContractors.Select(Function(z) z.Name).FirstOrDefault()
        })
```

End Function

I keep getting the same error:
"Unable to create a constant value of type . Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a workaround.
Created a View in database 2:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewContractEquipment
AS SELECT e.ContractEquipmentID, s.Name as SubContractorName
FROM dbo.ContractEquipments AS e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB2.dbo.SubContractors AS s ON e.SubContractorID = s.SubContractorID
```

I then added the view to my query and joined it with the main table:

```
    Return (From d In DB.ViewContractEquipments
        Join c in DB.ContractEquipments ON c.ContractEquipmentID equals d.ContractEquipmentID
        Select New With {
            .ContractID = c.ContractID,
            .EquipmentID = c.EquipmentID,
            .Inactive = c.Inactive,
            .SubContractorName = d.SubContractorName
        })
```

Not elegant, but it works!